# Multiple -> and dot

Tags: c++

I have just move to C++ couldn't understand these codes

```
QVariant v1 = con->getEnd1()->getProperty(fricstr);
```

or

```
Qstring Properties = getProperties().simplified().replace(","").split(",",Qstring::SkipEmptypart);
```

Could you explain the meaning of multiple `->` and `dot` in these codes?

Generally I understand the use of only one `->` as the value pointed to an object or `dot` as a method of an object. But with multiple I have no idea.

Comment: "I understand how `1+2` works, but not `1+2+3`" - what's not to understand? `1+2+3` evaluates `1+2`, and then `<whatever that was> + 3`. Likewise `con->getEnd1()->getProperty(fricstr)` evaluates `con->getEnd1()` and then `<whatever that was>->getProperty(fricstr)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QVariant v1 = con->getEnd1()->getProperty(fricstr);
```

Is the same as:

```
QVariant v1 = (con->getEnd1())->getProperty(fricstr);
```

That is, first you do `con->getEnd1()`. That evaluates to a pointer to some object, let's call the intermediate pointer `p`. Then you call `p->getProperty(fricstr)` on it. It's the same as chaining any operator (e.g. `1 + 2 + 3` is the same as `(1 + 2) + 3`).

To be really explicit it's equivalent to this, without storing the intermediate value:

```
auto&& p = con->getEnd1();
QVariant v1 = p-> getProperty(fricstr);
```

The same applies to `.`.

Comment: Small nitpick, if `con->getEnd1()` returns an object of class type with overloaded `operator->`, then your code is not equivalent

Comment: Thank Claudiu, Could you explain why it go from left to right but not backward?

Comment: @M.M: good point, thanks. Is it equivalent now with `auto&&` you think? May be more confusing than it's worth introducing `auto` here anyway ...

Comment: @Nhu Nguyen: That's the only way in which it makes sense. If you have an object `a` which has an object `b` which has an object `c` which has an object `d`, you can go down the object hierarchy with `a.b.c.d`. If it was right to left it'd equivalent to something like `a.(b.(c.d))`. But what would `b.(c.d)` mean?

Comment: Thank Claudiu, I get it now

Answer (score 2):

`x->` is short for `(*x).` (dereferencing)

`x->y->z`:
x->y returns y (from x)
y->z returns z (from y)

Comment: Thank Burkhard,
;Is it also similar for dot. for example: a.b.c 
;c is a member of b
;b is a member of a

Comment: @NhuNguyen no, `c` is a member of whatever `a.b` is